# Angular 6 Filter observable array with pipe

Tags: angular, observable, ngfor, angular-pipe

I display a list of objects in a ngFor loop and I would like to filter this list with a pipe.

My research led me to this:

filter-by.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { UserLink } from '../_models/user-link';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterBy'
})
export class FilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: User[], isActive: boolean): any {
        if (!items) { return []; }
        return items.filter(x => x.isActive === isActive);
    }
}
```

in my.component.html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items$|async|filterBy: {isActive: false}">
    <td>{{item.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{item.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{item.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

But the result is not what I expect: my array is empty.

What do I miss to make it work?

I tried my solution in this stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-46atle) and it works. But I still can't make it work in my project. I checked the properties of my object and the rest of the code but I can't see where my error is

[EDIT]

Problem solved! There was a casting missing between the object I was filtering on and the object I thought I was filtering on.!
Beginner's error!

Thanks for your adivces!

Comment: Probably `<tr *ngFor="let item of items$|async|filterBy: false">`

Comment: I still have the same issue: no result. I checked via the console if my filter parameter is correctly filled and there is no problem with that. It's like the filter doens't work or return empty array. Is it because I'm working with observable? Maybe I do something wrong with my items in the pipe code?

Answer (score 5):

**You shouldn't use pipes for filtering or sorting lists:**

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe

> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly
>   recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component
>   itself.

For example, you could convert the array to an observable and apply your filtering logic using pipeable RxJS operators:

```
Rx.Observable.from(items)
    .pipe(
         filter(item => item.size >= 1),
         map(item => "Item name: " + item.name),
         // more filtering logic
      ) 
    .subscribe(item => console.log(item))
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will update my code according this. But still I have a usecase for which it could be usefull: if you want to display one same list according to two different states (e.g. isActive status), isn't it heavier to duplicate code for active rows and inactive rows? even in this kind of case, the pipe still expensive?

Comment: I don't think you have to duplicate anything, you can just access your isActive boolean from within the *ngFor loop and use it to manipulate your template in whatever way you like, am I right?

Comment: It could be a good solution but i'm using a paginator so I'm not sure about the result.  But the simplier the better, duplicate lists should be the best way to do it without the filtering pipes.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to pass an object, your pipe accepts array and boolean as input.
 just try as follows

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items$|async|filterBy: false">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter your array like this:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of _items | filter:{label: filterText}">{{ item.label }}</li>
```

https://long2know.com/2016/11/angular2-filter-pipes/